# CakePHP: show/hide form control based on checkbox status

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, visibility

I have these 3 controls in a cakephp form:

```
echo $this->Form->control('recurring', ['empty' => true]);
echo $this->Form->control('recurring_months', ['options' => $months, 'empty' => true]);
echo $this->Form->control('recurring_start_date', ['empty' => true]);
```

I want the fields `recurring_months` and `recurring_start_date` to be hidden if the field `recurring` is not checked - true.

So I tried with this `javascript` code but is not working. How can I fix it?

```
<script>
    //hide recurring options if its not recurring
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#recurring').on('change', function(e){ 
            if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
                $('#recurring_months').show();
                $('#recurring_start_date').show();
            }
            else{ 
                $('#recurring_months').hide();
                $('#recurring_start_date').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at the HTML generated for your fields to confirm that you have the IDs right. But also, you might want to be hiding and showing something a little further up the DOM tree, so that the labels also disappear?

Comment: @GregSchmidt ok I saw that `recurring_months` id is `recurring-months` so now its working. But `recurring_start_date` has no id only names `recurring_start_date[year], recurring_start_date[month], recurring_start_date[day]` . So I tried to set the id manually like this: `echo $this->Form->control('recurring_start_date', ['id' => 'recurring-start-date', 'empty' => true]);` but again there is no id only name. So I can't hide the date field...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this, wrapping the inputs in a `div` and hiding it instead of hiding the fields individually:

```
echo $this->Form->control('recurring', ['empty' => true]);
echo $this->Html->tag('div',
    $this->Form->control('recurring_months', ['options' => $months, 'empty' => true]) .
    $this->Form->control('recurring_start_date', ['empty' => true]),
    ['id' => 'recurring_fields']
);

<script>
    //hide recurring options if its not recurring
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#recurring').on('change', function(e){ 
            if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
                $('#recurring_fields').show();
            }
            else{ 
                $('#recurring_fields').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```